# Hover over image to display text box using JavaScript only works on one image because I'm using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using javascript code to create a pop up box when you hover over images, but it's only working for one image because I believe its using IDs instead of classes, not sure though.
Take a look at the code I wrote:

Javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById('parent');
e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'inline';
}
e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="parent" src="img/Fruits.png" alt=Fruit">
                    <div id="popup">
                        <h5>
                            Apple:
                        </h5>
                        <h5 class="fruitDescription">
                            Apples taste good
                        </h5>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
#popup {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: #000;
opacity: 0.85;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 500px;
height: 382px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: -105px;
margin-left: 40px;
color: #1E90FF;
}

#popup:before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: -25px;
z-index: 1;
border: solid 15px transparent;
border-right-color: black;
color: #1E90FF;
}
```

I believe its not working because I'm using IDs. what I am trying to figure out is how to do exactly the same thing for multiple images.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a class to the images and use getElemenstByClassName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip javascript, add a class to img/popup, a wrapper and do it like this

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.85;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 382px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -105px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: #1E90FF;
  z-index: 1;
}
.popup:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: solid 15px transparent;
  border-right-color: black;
  color: #1E90FF;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.pic {
  z-index: 0;
}
.pic:hover + .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="pic" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/1/" alt="Fruit">
  <div class="popup">
    <h5>
      Apple:
    </h5>
    <h5 class="fruitDescription">
      Apples taste good
    </h5>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <img class="pic" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/2/" alt="Fruit">
  <div class="popup">
    <h5>
      Lemon:
    </h5>
    <h5 class="fruitDescription">
      Lemon is sour
    </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help but this one seems to be the perfect solution for me personally.

Comment: Hey, just an extra question, the icons are being displayed over the popup boxes when they're overlapping, do you know how can i make the popup box take priority when they overlap (make the popup box display over the icons)? hope that made sense.

EDIT: Nevermind, I got it. I just put in z-index: 1; in .pic:hover + .popup { }

Comment: @K.Bayyari Updated my answer. Use `z-index` on the `pic` which is lower than the `popup`. Or you meant something else?

Comment: Yeah thats what I did. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the same ID for all of your images, that is exactly the issue.  Your ID's must be unique within the document (so you're entire page); getElementById returns only one occurrence, as it assumes that you're following the standard.  You'll need to switch to using a class if you want to assign that onclick event to multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery this will handle multiple images after you change your ids to classes.

```
$('.parent').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).next('.popup').css('display', 'inline');
});

$('.parent').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).next('.popup').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dfurg918/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a js only solution:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer"), function(e) {
  e.onmouseover = function() {
    e.querySelector('.popup').style.display = 'inline';
  };
  e.onmouseout = function() {
    e.querySelector('.popup').style.display = 'none';
  };

});
```

```css
.imgContainer .popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.85;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 382px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -105px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: #1E90FF;
}
.imgContainer .popup:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid 15px transparent;
  border-right-color: black;
  color: #1E90FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img id="parent" src="img/Fruits.png" alt=Fruit ">
                                                
    <div class="popup " id="popup ">
        <h5>
            Apple:
        </h5>
        <h5 class="fruitDescription ">
            Apples taste good
        </h5>
    </div>
</div>                              
 <div class="imgContainer "> 
<img id="parent2 " src="img/Fruits.png " alt=Fruit">

  <div class="popup" id="popup2">
    <h5>
            Apple:
        </h5>
    <h5 class="fruitDescription">
            Apples taste good
        </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This "answers" your question, but i really think you should use the css solution by @LGSon above

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `id` should hold a unique value for each element you want to access.  `name` on the other hand could be the same for all your images, and then you could use `document.getElementsByName()`

**NOTE:** the 's', get *Element**s*** ByName

This returns an array of elements found.  Alternatively, `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` could be used to return a single element or array of elements, respectively, which conform to a particular selector.  That selector could be based on element type, class, name, existence of a particular attribute, the value of a particular attribute, and the list goes on.  Similarly, as I'm sure others will have posted by the time I'm done here, jQuery, with slightly different syntax than the native `querySelector[All]()`, can easily be used to select an array of jQuery objects that wrap the actual DOM element(s).

Using one of the above mentioned methods, you would select and attach to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events of each of the elements returned.

So just one example of how this could be put together...

1. Change `id='parent'` to `name='parent'`.
2. Select all elements with attribute `name='parent'`.
3. Attach events to each element in the set.

```js
(function() {
  var parents = document.querySelectorAll('img[name="parent"]');

  function alertMe() {
    alert('click is bound');
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    parents[i].onclick = alertMe;
  }
})();
```

```html
<img name="parent" src="img/Fruits.png" alt="Fruit&quot;">
<div id="popup">
  <h5>
                            Apple:
                        </h5>
  <h5 class="fruitDescription">
                            Apples taste good
                        </h5>
</div>
<img name="parent" src="img/Fruits.png" alt="Fruit&quot;">
<div id="popup">
  <h5>
                            Banana:
                        </h5>
  <h5 class="fruitDescription">
                            Bananas taste better
                        </h5>
</div>
```